# ExpandableListView with CursorTreeAdapter display of expanded group changes when scroll up and down

Tags: android, cursor, android-cursoradapter

After researching on this for several days now, I'm posting my question hoping you'll be able to help me.
I'm using an ExpandableListView with CursorTreeAdapter to display data from database I have. The data for the group is showing up with no problem. When I expand MORE when one group to show the children and I scroll up and down, the children data changes. e.g. parents A, B, C has one child each with data A1, B1 and C1. When I expand parent A and C and I scroll up and down, A1 data changes (in most cases to B1 data). Only if I collapse C will A1 data show again for parent A.

The child layout

Can you advise as to why it is happenning and what can be done?

Here is my CursorTreeAdapter code from the newGroupView, bindGroupView, newChildView, bindChildView:

```
    public class MyCursorTreeAdapter extends CursorTreeAdapter {

    String name = "";
    String phone = "";
    String cityStreet = "";
    String userNote2 = "";
    DBConnector values;
    long id = 0;
    DBConnector cmpDb;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context context;
    int oldGroupPosition;

    public MyCursorTreeAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor, context);
        this.context = context;
        values = new DBConnector(context);
        this.values = values;
        cmpDb = new DBConnector(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_view, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) {

        TextView textsubText1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subText1);
        TextView textsubText2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subText2);

        textsubText1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(values.Name)));
        textsubText2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(values.Name)));

        userNote2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(values.Note2));
    }

    @Override
    public View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, parent, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindChildView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {
        values.open();
        TextView nameTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView phoneTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
        TextView addressTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);

        ImageButton btData1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btData1);
        ImageButton btData2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btData2);
        ImageButton btSaveData = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btSaveData);

        extractDataFromUserNote2();

        nameTv.setText(""+ name);
        phoneTv.setText(""+ phone);
        addressTv.setText(""+ cityStreet);

        android.view.View.OnClickListener doWithBtData1 = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // action on btData1
            }
        };

        android.view.View.OnClickListener doWithBtData2 = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // action on btData2
            }
        };


        android.view.View.OnClickListener doWithBtSaveData = new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                // action on btSaveData
            }
        };

        btData1.setOnClickListener(doWithBtData1);
        btData2.setOnClickListener(doWithBtData2);
        btSaveData.setOnClickListener(doWithBtSaveData);
        values.close();

    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        return getCursor();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount (int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

        @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed (int groupPosition) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded (int groupPosition) {
    }

    protected Cursor setChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        return groupCursor;
    }

    @Override
    public void setGroupCursor (Cursor cursor) {

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after many days of research I was able to find a way **around** this problem. I added an OnScroll call back function that collapses the expanded group once the user is scrolling in the list.

I wish I could find a more elegant way, but it is working.

Here is the code:

On the main parameter list:

```
    int previousItem = -1;
```

The call back function:

```
    elv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    // This call back function close the group on scroll. It is used to override the but of view change.
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (previousItem != -1 && scrollState == 1) {
            elv.collapseGroup(previousItem );
            previousItem = -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    }
});
```

The call back function to manage the Expand/Collapse of the group:

```
    elv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if(groupPosition != previousItem ) {
            elv.collapseGroup(previousItem );
        }
        previousItem = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you.